# Why does sourcing a script not print out to stdout?

Tags: r

In a R session, I source a simple r script whose content is:

```
x = c(1,2)
x
```

as

```
source('my.r')
```

I wonder why running it in the R session doesn't show any output?

(I find that I can use `print()` to show the value of `x`.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It is the way `source` is configured. You can change it with the options `echo` and `print.eval`:

> `echo` logical; if TRUE, each expression is printed after parsing,
>   before evaluation.
>
> `print.eval` logical; if TRUE, the result of
>   eval(i) is printed for each expression i; defaults to the value of
>   echo.

So try `source("my.r", print.eval=TRUE)`

Answer (score 4):

So far as I understand it,  when you run `source`, you are starting a separate environment inside which `source` is executing, just like any other function.  As such,  `x` "prints" the value of x inside that environment, but the console is one environment "up" the chain.

Try, for example,

```
foo<-function(x) {
x
return(4)
}
```

EDIT:  James has more directly answered the "how" part of your question.

Comment: (+1), there, now you can see ghosts :)

Comment: if you include `str(x)` in your function and call it, it prints `str` output. Would you know why this is? I can't see a print method for `str` if I call `methods(print)`. thanks

Comment: @user63230  There's no `print` method because `str` does not return anything.  It prints directly to the console.  How it does that successfully I don't know - you'll have to grab the source code for the `utils` package and dig in there.